# Android c++ AAsset_read reads wrong data

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, assets, readfile

I read content of text files from assets. However, if I read second file then I get wrong result. It is mixed with previous file.

Here is first file, this is correctly written to buffer by AAsset_read:

```
uniform   mat4 uMVPMatrix;

attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 a_Color;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main() 
{ 
   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
   v_Color = a_Color;
}
```

Here is second file, this is how it really looks and is expected to be written to buffer:

```
precision mediump float; 

varying vec4 v_Color;
uniform float alpha;
 
void main() 
{ 
    gl_FragColor = v_Color;
    gl_FragColor.a = gl_FragColor.w * alpha;
}
```

However, this is what is written to buffer by AAsset_read. It adds "v_Color = a_Color;\n}"" at the end, this is part of content from first file.

```
"precision mediump float; \n\nvarying vec4 v_Color;\nuniform float alpha;\n \nvoid main() \n{ \n    gl_FragColor = v_Color;\n    gl_FragColor.a = gl_FragColor.w * alpha;\n}v_Color = a_Color;\n}"
```

Here is method what I use:

```
std::string Assets::getTextFile(const char *file) {
        AAsset *asset = AAssetManager_open(android_assetManager, file, AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);

        int size = AAsset_getLength(asset);       
        char *bits = new char[size];

        AAsset_read(asset, bits, size);
        AAsset_close(asset);

        std::string a(bits);

        return a;
}
```

I am on android 13 and ndk is 24.0.8215888

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: `char *bits = new char[size];` We think bytes are read: `char *bytes = new char[size];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AAsset_read`'s job is to read bytes from an asset, it does *NOT* add a terminating NUL byte.
You should tell the `std::string` constructor the exact size:

```
std::string a(bits, size);
```

You also forgot to free `bits` again. You can improve the code by having `AAsset_read` put its data directly into your string and skipping the extra copy.

```
std::string ret(size, 0);
AAsset_read(asset, ret.data(), size);
```

Comment: AAsset_read(asset, ret.data(), size); can't take ret.data(). It throws error: no matching function for call to 'AAsset_read'

Comment: Thank you, if I delete buffer and set string size then seems it works fine

Comment: `.data()` only started producing a `char*` as of C++17. If you are writing for an older version of C++ you may need to pass `&ret[0]` instead.